# Why do I need to use the ‘conjuntivo’ or ‘subjuntivo’ after the relative pronoun "que"?

Tags: modo-subjuntivo, orações-subordinadas

I'm struggling a little with this kind of sentences:

> Você quer que eu te ligue?

Why is there the necessity of the *conjuntivo*? Do you have an external resource about the *conjuntivo* where I can inform myself about its usage?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A verb in **conjuntivo** or **subjuntivo** (I think *subjuntivo* is the preferred name in Brazil) mood indicates that the action described by the verb may or may not happen. Take the following examples:

> (1) Ele liga-te.
>
> (2) Eu quero que ele te ligue.

(1) expresses a fact, so we use the *indicative* **ele liga**. But in (2) it is not a fact that he will actually going to **ligar**; the sentence just says that I want him to. So we use the *conjuntivo* **ele ligue**. It is not because of **que** (by the way, in that sentence, **que** is a conjunction, not a pronoun): it is because the **eu quero** shows that **ligar** is just my wish, it is not guaranteed to happen.

This use of the *conjuntivo/subjuntivo* has parallels in the use of subjunctive in English, especially US English. Comapare:

> Eu sugiro/peço/insisto que **ele seja** pontual — I suggest/ask/insist that **he be** punctual.

Again, just because I suggest or insist that he be punctual that does not mean he is actually going to be punctual.

Other examples where the *conjuntivo* expresses wish, desire, hope, command, requirement, request, need, advice:

> Eu quero/desejo/espero que tu lhe ligues.
>
> Eu ordeno/exijo/mando que tu lhe ligues.
>
> O sucesso do empreendimento requer/exige que todos trabalhem.
>
> Ele pede/suplica/implora que tu lhe ligues.
>
> Eu preciso/necessito que tu me ligues.
>
> Eu recomendo/aconselho que tu me ligues.
>
> É desejável/importante/essencial/imperativo que tu me ligues.

The *conjuntivo* is not used only for resquest, advices, etc... It may simple express doubt or uncertainty.

> Duvido que ele te ligue
>
> Não creio/acho/acredito que ele te ligue.
>
> É possível/natural/impensável/incerto que ele te ligue.

And it can be used without the preceding **que**

> Talvez ele te ligue.

Now verbs like *pensar, julgar, supor, etc...* can be followed by *que + presente do indicativo* or *que + conjuntivo*. The latter expresses a higher degree of uncertainty. So if you say:

> Penso que ele está em casa

you sound more confident of his being at home than if you say

> Penso que ele esteja em casa.

If you have **verb in pretérito imperfeito or condicinal + que** then you use the *pretérito imperfeito do conjuntivo*:

> Ele queria/desejava/desejaria/esperaria que tu lhe ligasses.
>
> Ele exigiria/ordenaria que tu lhe ligasses.
>
> Eu gostaria que tu me ligasses.
>
> Seria desejável que tu lhe ligasses.

The **relative pronoun que** may be followed by indicative or subjunctive depending on what you mean. Compare:

> (3) O homem que ligou ontem está aqui.
>
> (4) Diz a qualquer pessoa que ligue que eu não estou.

In example (3) a man has in fact called, so we use the inidicative *homem **que ligou**;* in (4) people may or may not call, so we use the subjunctive *pessoa **que ligue**.*

And here is the subjunctive-rich [O dia em que nasci, moura e pereça](http://users.isr.ist.utl.pt/%7Ecfb/VdS/v057.txt).

I hope this helps

Comment: Wow, that's a very comprehensive and clear answer. Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad you like it. I'll add a little something about relative pronouns after lunch. They can be followed by the subjunctive too.