# Is esteja/estiver used when talking about the future?

Tags: gramática, português-europeu, modo-subjuntivo

I've noticed that that while in Spanish it's become standard to use the **present subjunctive** in the cases such as

```
cuando esté en Africa te lo haré saber
```

, in Portuguese the **future subjunctive** one would be used instead:

```
quando eu estiver na África...
```

and never the present form.

Is this correct?

Is not, or even if so, when would the present form be used then?

```
quando eu esteja na África...
```

Comment: It is a feature of _quando_. See this Q&A https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4345/can-present-subjunctive-be-used-to-indicate-near-future?rq=1 for much more detail.

Comment: Yes, quando clauses take future subjunctive in Portuguese.

Answer (score 1):

This issue and similar ones have been discussed at length in this Q&A [Can present subjunctive be used to indicate near future?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4345/can-present-subjunctive-be-used-to-indicate-near-future?rq=1)

To summarise the issue in the current question *quando* always uses the future subjunctive not the present subjunctive. It is just a grammatical rule which you have to learn. Note though that if it is a timeless use (when I am in Africa I eat the local food) the indicative is used.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the **future subjunctive** is used with "*quando*", because it refers to an event in the future. This tense is something quite remarkable to have when it comes to Romance languages!The **present subjunctive**, however, is used when there is no certainty and it is *currently* happening.

For instance:

> "Que ele **esteja** certo!" (May he be right).